# cURL/Guzzle request from sub1.example.local (localhost) to sub2.example.local (localhost) USES SAME DATABASE

Tags: php, laravel, curl, laravel-5

I am trying to sent api request with guzzle and also cURL from sub1.example.local (localhost) to sub2.example.local (localhost). Both laravel 5.4 projects. But it uses database of sub1.example.local.

Even using `session_write_close();`

```
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://sub2.example.local/api/user/login");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "email=\"email@example.com\"&password=\"big_secret\"");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECT_TO, ['hesabatlar.local','80','sub2.example.local','80']);

        $headers = array();
        $headers[] = 'Accept: application/json';
        $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
        $headers[] = 'Host: hr.hesabatlar.local';

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

        session_write_close();

        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        if (curl_errno($ch)) {
            echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
        }
        curl_close ($ch);
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that when requesting sub2 .env of sub 2 is not loaded and sub1 .env file used. So I get sub1 database. For more details see source. If write your configurations in config folder it works fine.

This issue happens only in Windows and is working fine in Linux. Not sure what is causing this issue.

Source: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/16407